# vsftpd - restrict users to custom directory not working in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, server, permissions, ftp, vsftpd

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 server and I installed vsftpd.

I created a new FTP user following this tutorial: https://devanswers.co/installing-ftp-server-vsftpd-ubuntu-18-04/

I want to lock the user to the folder: `/var/www/html/mydomain.com/` but I am unable, no matter what I set in the `/etc/vsftpd.conf` file.

I tried for example these suggestions:

```
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
chroot_local_user=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
```

I also tried adding:

```
local_root=/
```

or

```
local_root=/var/www/html/mydomain.com/
```

The user can login successfully but I am unable to lock it to any folder. Any advice will be great. Thanks.

Comment: I updated the title, it's Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of searching, I found the answer by myself:

run in terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

At the end of the file add:

```
Match User yourusername
ForceCommand internal-sftp
PasswordAuthentication yes
ChrootDirectory /var/www/html/yourdomain.com/
PermitTunnel no
AllowAgentForwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
```

Replace yourusername with the name of the ftp user that you created and also replace the ChrootDirectory path.

run in terminal:

```
sudo systemctl restart sshd
```

More details here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-enable-sftp-without-shell-access-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Your answer is for SSH, not for FTP